# Incorrect view size when using XIB from framework in a demo project

Tags: ios, frameworks, ios8, constraints

I am building a framework with resources bundle (XIBs, images, etc.) using Apple's static framework project.

I am also running a demo project on a real iPhone 6 device using the framework, but as I present the XIB from some view controller in the demo project, I see the XIB only at 320 x 568 points (and not in 375 x 667 as it should on iPhone 6). Also after inspecting `self.view.frame` of the framework's XIB, I get 320 x 568. On iPhone 5 - everything looks good.

The strange thing, is that if I set in the framework's XIB simulated metric to iPhone 4.7-inch (instead of inferred) and launch the app, I see it good on iPhone 6, but bad on iPhone 5.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

[image]